# What is String to ZonedDateTime conversion error

Tags: java

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;  

public class ZonedDateTimeExample1{  
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ZonedDateTime zone = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-10-05T08:20:10");  
        System.out.println(zone);  
    }  
}
```

This results in a

> String to Date convertion error

The `String` is without time zone. How to convert it to `ZonedDateTime` with UTC time zone added.
Please let me know why default time zone is not taking in `ZonedDateTime.parse`

Getting below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 2016-10-05T08:20:10 could not be parsed at index 19
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
 at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
 at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:582)
 at ZonedDateTimeExample1.main(ZonedDateTimeExample1.java:4)
```

Comment: Where is the zone in that `String`? The datetime you are trying to parse does not have a zone or offset. You would have to use `LocalDateTime.parse(...)` here and attach a zone afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** See the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ZonedDateTime zone = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-10-05T08:20:10")
                                      .atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
    System.out.println(zone); 
}
```

You cannot directly parse a `String` that doesn't have a time zone to a `ZonedDateTime`. You have to parse it to a `LocalDateTime` (date and time of day **without offset or zone**) and attach a zone afterwards.

Alternatively, you can use the `ZoneId` with the `DateTimeFormatter` itself e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
                                .withZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
    
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.from(dtf.parse("2016-10-05T08:20:10"));
    System.out.println(zdt);
}
```